# $I(X:Y|Z=z) \leq I(X:Y|Z)$?

Tags: probability, correlation, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, entropy

$X,Y$ and $Z$ are discrete random variables. $I$ is the mutual information. The question is in the title. If the inequality is true, how would you show it? Thanks.

My intuition: having more information on the conditional variable $Z$ ($e.g.$ $Z=z$) decreases the correlations between $X$ and $Y$, as visualized by the decrease in the intersection surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the inequality does not hold for all $z$ (the support of $Z$)

$I(X;Y|Z=z)$ is a function of the random variable $Z$, $g(Z)$ it can take different values for different realizations $z$.

$I(X;Y|Z)$ is the expected value of that function, $E_Z[g(Z)]$, a weighted average that must lie between the largest and smallest value g(Z) can take.